# Spinner menu с помощью Tkinter'a

Tags: python, tkinter

Есть ли возможность в Tkinter реализовать, назовем его, спиннер меню.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: С какой целью на классическом UI нужна имитация мобильных элементов управления? В tkinter для подобного есть комбобоксы/листбоксы

Answer (score 0):

Вы можете использовать в качестве спиннер-меню виджет Spinbox с заданными значениями.
Например:

```
from tkinter import *
w = Tk()
w.title('Spin')
w.geometry('550x500')
s = Spinbox(w,values=('test','python','Spin'),width=8) # values - Допустимые значения
s.pack()
w.mainloop()
```